# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, eclipse

```
protected void thisWindowClosing(WindowEvent e)
 {
    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(e.getWindow() , "¿DESEA CERRAR EL PROGRAMA?",
        "Confirmación", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
     if(n==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
      {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GRACIAS POR UTILIZAR EL PROGRAMA");
        System.exit(0);
      }
   }
```

Cuando Selecciono `SI`, la ventana se cierra pero cuando selecciono NO la venta igual se cierra, quisiera saber como hacer para que al momento que seleccione NO, no se cierre la ventana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede, debido a los `JFrame` tienen una propiedad `defaultCloseOperation`[windowevents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html#windowevents) por defecto con valor `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` , tendrías que cambiar esta propiedad  a `DO_NOTHING` de forma gráfica o `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` mediante código.  Para luego al seleccionar la opción `NO` de tu `showConfirmDialog` NO se cierre el `JFrame`.

Para cambiarlo si es de forma gráfica , dirigete a las propiedades y ubica y cambia su valor. a Nivel de código sería

```
form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me servió

Comment: Si te ayudo a resolver tus dudas. Marcar mi respuesta como aceptada.